# How do I express "K extends keyof T such that T[K] is of type V"?

Tags: typescript

I want to create a function signature like this:

```
countBy<R, V>(objs: R[], iteratee: ((x: R) => V) | keyof R): Map<V, number> {}
```

In the style of lodash, `iteratee` should *either* be a function `(x: R) => V` or the shorthand `keyof R`:

```
countBy(pizzas, pizza => pizza.sauce)
countBy(pizzas, 'sauce')
```

How can I tell Typescript that if I use the shorthand (`'sauce'`), `R[keyof R]` must produce a value of type `V`?

Comment: To me it doesn't make any sense the current return type of `countBy`, is it really `Map<V, number>`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you won't need to type the function body (which is trickier), you can create two overloads to achieve this:

```
function countBy<R, V>(objs: R[], iteratee: ((x: R) => V)): Map<V, number>
function countBy<R, K extends keyof R, V extends R[K]>(objs: R[], iteratee: K): Map<V, number>
function countBy<R, V>(objs: R[], iteratee: ((x: R) => V) | keyof R): Map<V, number> {
  return {} as any
}
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBO4oCECeAeASgGkQDUA%20ACjgCMArAZwC5FcBtAXUJigFMAnAQ25dGZMgA9GuAJSIAvCWKTJjALJ8ADtiKEwIALaVeJALAAoUJFgJkqMBhwFEAaURdR3MABNaiANZdMcMBMhEQublye3iyOrORUdBJsHNz8goyOSoiqGlqIOvqGpubQ8EgoaFh4IXE0DExJiJy8AlxCiCLiTNJyCogAPr7%20gV0q6praegY88gDepoiIPFxQIDxIMwC%20iHzefGCYphumpihgtFCIajAAXtc7sojMM7R8IBBtAORQcLoCcB%20ECAAC1atDaUB4IC4G1YxxMp3OiG45wAjA9yrYsGQrrcdoQcXdZPICXwAHQvN5cSSmAD0NIWCwAegB%20OEIi7IqAAJnRNjs2Jud1ohA%20FPeH2pJjpDMQLLZCERnIAzLyKpgBbjhYgPsDQVwJbT6Qy5SYgA)

Answer (score 1):

To expand upon Oblosys' answer, here is another set of overloads that would achieve your goal:

```js
function countBy<R, K extends keyof R>(
  objs: R[],
  iteratee: K
): Map<R[K], number>;

function countBy<R, V>(
  objs: R[],
  iteratee: (x: R) => V
): Map<V, number>;

function countBy<R>(
  objs: R[],
  iteratee: ((x: R) => unknown) | keyof R
): Map<unknown, number> {
  /* ... your code ... */
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to bother with overloads or you want to have a typed body, you can try the following signature, which takes advantage of the fact that you can put conditional types in the return type:

```js
function countBy<R, I extends ((x: R) => any) | keyof R>(
  objs: R[],
  iteratee: I
): Map<
  I extends keyof R ? R[I] : I extends (x: R) => any ? ReturnType<I> : never,
  number
> {
  /* ... your code ... */
}
```